# как исправить ошибку в Python TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable помогите пожалуйста пишу на питон 3

Tags: python

```
number = 1000

def tut_ne_balo_mata():
        while True:
            number -= 7
            print(number)

funcs = (tut_ne_balo_mata)
while (my_choice := input('\tты хочешь стать dead inside\n' +
                         '1. да\n' +
                         '2. нет\n' +
                         'выбери пункут меню')) != '2':
    try:
        my_choice = int(my_choice)
    except ValueError:
        print('Ошибка ввода, попробуйте еще раз...')
    else:
        if 0 < my_choice < 2:
            funcs[my_choice - 1]()
        else:
            print('нет такого пункта меню')
```

Comment: [дубликаты-дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+object+is+not+subscriptable)

Comment: За мат в коде сразу минус, не думая. А по сути если внутри скобок нет запятой, то что ставили вы скобки, что нет - без разницы. Кортеж у вас не получится. Поэтому лучше делать списки, со списком таких промахов не бывает.

Comment: ошибка в 19 строке

Comment: вам даже строку указали, в которой вы пытаетесь обратиться к скалярной переменной `funcs` как к массиву.

Comment: код довольно сырой поэтому тут есть дубликаты а где вы нашли маты?

Comment: `funcs` у вас в итоге просто ссылается на вашу функцию. Что вы хотите получить с помощью индексирования функции? А насчёт мата - ну не прикидывайтесь, что ещё может означать название вашей функции?

Comment: о спасибо а я тупил

Comment: тут точно нет матов вы врете

Comment: Возможно, мне показалось. Если бы там было `xyz` - никаких вопросов. А то что было я не могу себе представить откуда могло ещё взяться.

Answer (score 0):

```
    number = 1000
    
def func():
    global number
    while True:
        number -= 7
        print(number)
    
# funcs = (tut_ne_balo_mata)  что это ?

my_choice = input('\tты хочешь стать dead inside\n 1. да\n 2. нет\n выбери пункут меню')
if my_choice != '2':
    try:
        my_choice = int(my_choice)
    except ValueError:
        print('Ошибка ввода, попробуйте еще раз...')
else:
    print(func())

# Подумай насчёт этого блока, так не понял чего ты хотел добиться
# этим блоком
''' if 0 < my_choice < 2:
            funcs[my_choice - 1]
'''

'''     else:
            print('нет такого пункта меню')'''
```

funcs ссылался на tut_ne_balo_mata() как я понял. А потом вы пишете funcs[my_choice - 1]. Очень странно и не ясно что вы хотели этим сказать.